# Storing string byte representations of multiple files

Tags: android, string, byte, store

I need to do an HTTP post of information including String byte representations of multiple files in a single HTTP Post. I'm getting quite a lot of byte allocation errors and was wondering if there was a better way of storing this information for later post to server?

I've basically taken quite a few picture files, and I'm packaging them up into a single HTTP Post string of the format:

`name="string byte representation of picture file"&timestamp="time"&gps="latitude""longitude",`etc.

Logcat:

```
03-09 22:26:41.329: E/dalvikvm-heap(8716): Out of memory on a 5932438-byte allocation.
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x40020ba0 self=0xddd0
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   | sysTid=8716 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=-1345025972
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:~97)
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:157)
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:217)
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at mfc.generalguixapi8.SaveData2.saveData(SaveData2.java:169)
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at mfc.generalguixapi8.SaveData2.onCreate(SaveData2.java:34)
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-09 22:26:41.329: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-09 22:26:41.339: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 22:26:41.339: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-09 22:26:41.339: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-09 22:26:41.339: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-09 22:26:41.339: I/dalvikvm(8716):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 22:26:41.339: W/dalvikvm(8716): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:97)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:157)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:217)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at mfc.generalguixapi8.SaveData2.saveData(SaveData2.java:169)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at mfc.generalguixapi8.SaveData2.onCreate(SaveData2.java:34)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-09 22:26:41.339: E/AndroidRuntime(8716):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you post some or LogCat errors?

Comment: Could you post the where the data gets sent.  Also, how much data are trying to send?

Comment: @MikeD I'm not posting the data anywhere yet. I'm just trying to package all the data up into a single String. And I'm not sure how much data really, it'll differ. Probably the string byte representations of about 20 pictures and 20 videos and 20 audio files at a time at a maximum?

Comment: I'm thinking now maybe to save each chunk in an xml file. But I'm not sure how to append text without loading the whole string into the application first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved using [Sending file > 1MB using HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745514/sending-file-1mb-using-http-post)

I was getting an OutofMemory issue in the above link, and solved it by saving the data to a FileOutputStream and sending the information to the server in chunks.