# Sending file > 1MB using HTTP POST

Tags: android, http-post, large-file-upload

I'm sending video and audio files from my Android application to `Wampserver`, some of these can get quite large and I tend to get `OutofMemory` issues when the file is approximately over `1MB` in size.

I convert each file individually into a byte stream. I think the byte stream is too large hence the `OutofMemory`.

How can I stop this error from occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the link Maxium suggested here:

[**Uploading files to HTTP server using POST on Android.**](http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)

I then found this [Out of Memory error in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777230/out-of-memory-error-in-android) to fix the error.

Replace:

```
while (bytesRead > 0)
{
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}
```

with:

```
while (bytesRead > 0){
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    byte byt[]=new byte[bufferSize];
    fileInputStream.read(byt);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}
```

Comment: @Maxim Yes I fixed it. I upvoted your answer because it partly solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I was just curious did it work for you or not as I didn't have time to write a server part to find out why it is still didn't work. Scores don't matter

Answer (score 4):

Look at this example:

[**Uploading files to HTTP server using POST on Android.**](http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)

Comment: Does that code split the file into parts or something? Although I don't think it's that kind of problem. I convert each file individually into a byte stream. I think the byte stream is too large hence the OutofMemory..

Comment: It gives OutputStream of the connection and reads the file into the stream. outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream(); Server needs to write that stream somewhere. If you read file by 1024 bytes it will never take more memmory then 1K. make a maxBufferSize = 4096. When you are opening file for streaming it doesn't get loaded into memmory

Comment: If you show the piece of code that does upload, will be easier to guess what's wrong there.

Comment: This does work for files bigger than 1MB, but now I am having trouble sending a file which is over 7MB in size. I get the OutOfMemory issue again..

Answer (score 0):

When you have large size of data like big file or big image/good quality image to send to server then you can send it in parts/chunks.

First make Http Connection with the Server and then send chunks with `DataOutputStream` Class. On the server side same, you need to implement code for receiving these chunks and make them in one file once you get all the chunks.

Comment: This is what TCP/IP was invented for